# Eclipse SSH key generation - key strength

Tags: eclipse, ssh, rsa

The Eclipse SSH key generation screen (General -> Network Connections -> SSH2) generates a 1024 bit RSA key, which is too weak to be used (http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2012/09/10/minimum-rsa-public-key-lengths-guidelines-or-rules.html)

Is there a way to increase this to 2048 or 4096 bits? I know I could use `ssh-keygen` or puttygen but I'm trying to keep things simple for other developers.

Comment: I believe there is no way in Eclipse. Everyone I know uses putty on Windows for doing similar things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've raised a bug for this with the Eclipse team: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404714